# Plugin version not updating in Wordpress Plugin Directory

Tags: wordpress

My WordPress plugin is showing the wrong version number in the Wordpress Plugin Directory. According to the documentation, the version number listed on the Directory should correspond with the version number on the `readme.txt` of the plugin.

My current `readme.txt` from the plugin's current repository reads `1.1.2`. This can also be verified at through the plugin's Wordpress Plugin Directory page. However, the button to download the plugin still reads version `1.0` and I am not sure why!

The `Stable Tag` is also entered as `1.1.2`.

Comment: are you sure you update the Version in the readme.txt?

Comment: Yes. The readme is showing Stable Tag 1.1.2 ... however the Plugin Directory is still showing version 1.0

Comment: check with it, https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt, it is standard readme.txt

Comment: Have you updated the plugin headers inside the plugin's main PHP file to match readme.txt? Not sure if that makes any difference though...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by updating the version number and trying again.

The solution was originally found here: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/wordpress/version-number-not-updating-in-wordpress-plugin-directory/

The other suggested solutions are: 
1) making sure the line endings are consistent across all files and
2) giving up and emailing support@wordpress.org (from the same email address that owns the plugin) – link them to your plugin on the directory and explain the issue you’re having.